# Could you help me understand the notation of forces on the plate?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, elasticity, stress-strain

I am so confused about the notation in this book with the one I learned before.
So could anybody help me comprehend the notation in this figure?

1. I am not clear about is the notation of the moments. As far as I know, $M_x$ means the moment about x axis, but when you see $M_x$+$\frac{\partial M_x}{\partial x}$$dx$ on the right side of the plate, it rotates about y axis. Other moments show same notations.
2. Again as you can see on the right side of the plate, the notation of $Q_x$+$\frac{\partial Q_x}{\partial x}$$dx$ seems awkward because the direction of this force is not parallel with x axis, but with z axis.

So are they just typos? (I think they are not typos...)
Or am I ignorant of the notation on the plate elements?

Thanks!

Figure from
*Advanced Mechanics of Materials and Applied Elasticity*, Ugural and Fenster

[image: Advanced Mechanics of Materials and Applied Elasticity_Ugural]

Comment: Does the text include some kind of key or mention of the notation? As far as I can see (look at the left and top of the image), the figure is labelled with two axes of symmetry. The $x$ notation seems to be applied to effects happening in relation to the $x$-symmetry axis, likewise with the $y$-symmetry axis. This applies both to torque and force. And $xy$ notation seems to be used for effects that "merge" into the domain of the other, so to say. I'd expect there to be a definition of this notation somewhere in the book related to this figure.

Comment: @Steeven No specifc notation about this... I had no trouble understanding the notation of beam or rod cases, or on the 2D explanations in this book, but this plate case looks quiet different than other cases. I just want to know who is wrong about this, book or me... By the way, $M_xy$ looks like a twisting moment.

Comment: After I read the book many times, I reached a conclusion which looks 80% sure(give me any opinions if you guys don't agree with me!). Unlike stress or strain, which is expressed in standard way(e.g. $\tau_{xy}$, $\sigma_{xx}$), notation of moments or forces are quiet informal. I think the author of this book used subscripts including x to show forces and moments occur parallel to xz plane and those including y when forces and moments occur parallel to yz plane.

Comment: That picture is way too cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a chance to look at that text. Here, $M_i$ does not refer to a moment around an $i$-axis (as you've noticed). It refers to the moment produced by the variation in stress $\sigma_i$ along the $z$-axis.

Thus, $M_x$ is associated with the normal stress $\sigma_x$, $M_y$ with the normal stress $\sigma_y$, and $M_{xy}$ with the shear stress $\tau_{xy}$. (As a consequence, $M_x$ acts around the $x$-axis, $M_y$ around the $y$-axis, and $M_{xy}$ around both axes.)